# Google Yolo doesn't return an access_token nor gender info

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

I'm implementing the one-tap signIn for my site.
With the normal Google SignIn, i can do this:

```
window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
   .then((googleUser) => sendAccessTokenToServer(googleUser.getAuthResponse().access_token))
```

Thanks to **access_token**, on the server side I can do something like this and get profile informations like gender:

```
GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setClientSecrets(clientId, secret).setRequestInitializer((request -> {
          HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
          headers.setAuthorization("Bearer " + accessToken);
        })).build();
```

But when using the **googleyolo**, with hint() or retrieve() i cannot get the access_token, but just the idToken:
googleyolo

```
.hint({
    supportedAuthMethods: [googleUrl, 'googleyolo://id-and-password', scope],
    supportedIdTokenProviders: [
       {
         uri: googleUrl,
         clientId
       }]
     }).then(
          (credential) => {
            if (credential.idToken) {
              sendidTokenToServer(credential.idToken);
            }
          }
```

But the problem is, when i do on server-side:

```
GoogleIdToken idToken = null;
    try {
      idToken = verifier.verify(accessToken);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (idToken != null) {
      GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

      // Print user identifier
      String userId = payload.getSubject();
      System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);

      // Get profile information from payload
      String email = payload.getEmail();
      boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
      String name = (String) payload.get("name");
      String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
      String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
      String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
      String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");
```

I don't get informations like the gender.
Is it possible to get an **access_token** from **googleyolo** or getting the gender inside the **idToken**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the product manager at Google for this library. Accessing gender is not currently supported via the one-tap library. My suggestion would be show your own UI to collect gender info (could just be one more tap on M / F / other / skip, etc.), as you would have to anyway if this data were not available or user signed up manually. Not all Google users have gender info set or accessible via API anyway.